# jqGrid - sort the grid on loading in descending order

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to sort a static grid (made from HTML table) to sort on load using the following snippet...

```
$("#my_table").setGridParam({sortname:'my_date'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

This does the job but it sorts the date in ascending order. How can I make it sort on load in descending order?

Regards

Comment: Please refer to my answer on :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169299/using-the-sortgrid-method-to-sort-a-column-in-descending-order/53296863#53296863

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `sortorder: "desc"`

```
$("#my_table").setGridParam({sortname:'my_date', sortorder: 'desc'})
   .trigger('reloadGrid');
```