# Using the "sortGrid" method to sort a column in descending order?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that I'm sorting client-side, so I'm using the **sortGrid** method.  However, this method only accepts two parameters: column name and if the grid should be reloaded.

I want to conditionally **use this method to sort ascending AND descending.**  However, since sort order isn't a parameter, the method **defaults to ascending sort.**

I currently have a work-around where I call the **sortGrid** method twice if the column should be sorted in descending order:

```
if (sortCol) {
    $("#gridID").sortGrid(sortCol);
    //If descending, need to apply the sort a 2nd time
    if (sortOrder === "desc") {
        $("gridID").sortGrid(sortCol);
    }
}
```

This seems to do the trick, at least when testing on my localhost.  However, when moved to a live environment, it seems to not work every once in a while.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the sort order of the grid using the api like so:

```
$("#gridID").jqGrid('setGridParam', {sortorder: "desc"}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

The api call will trigger the reload of the grid so you should not issue the reload via the sortGrid method call.

Comment: I've already tried using that.  Regardless if I setGridParam before or after sortGrid, sortGrid just resets the sort order to "asc".

Comment: Tried again with the ".trigger('reloadGrid');" piece, and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, sortGrid() doesn't work in descending order.

But, the issue is not that it's not working, it's actually the loadonce:true property.

If you use loadonce:true jqGrid change the datatype parameters to 'local' after the first load of data from the grid. All next grid reloading (sorting, paging, filtering) works local. If you want refresh the grid data from the server one more time you should set datatype to its original value ('json' or 'xml').

Hence, we need to be a little tricky to overcome this and execute the sortGrid() after loadComplete:

Here is the code which works perfectly to select the page and sort option after the grid is loaded.

```
    $('#myGrid').trigger("reloadGrid");

//SORTED_COLUMN is Global
var  DEFAULT_SORTED = false;
if (SORTED_COLUMN.index != undefined)
    DEFAULT_SORTED = true;

$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype : "local",
    autowidth : true,
    altclass : "jqgridAltRow",
    altRows :true,
    shrinkToFit :true,
    loadonce: true,
    data :data,
    editurl: 'clientArray', // to give a successful call after inline editing,
    page: CURRENT_PAGE,
    //method : 'post',
    cellEdit : 'true',
    cellsubmit : 'remote',
    beforeRequest: function () {
        responsive_jqgrid($(".ui-jqgrid"));
    },
    onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
        SORTED_COLUMN.index = index;
        SORTED_COLUMN.columnIndex = columnIndex;
        SORTED_COLUMN.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    },
    loadComplete: function(){
        $.fn.jqm = undefined;



        setTimeout(function(){
            if(DEFAULT_SORTED){
                DEFAULT_SORTED = false;
                $('#myGrid').jqGrid('sortGrid', SORTED_COLUMN.index, false, SORTED_COLUMN.sortOrder);
                $('#myGrid').trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: CURRENT_PAGE}]);
            }
        }, 100);

        ...
```

if(DEFAULT_SORTED) This check is important, otherwise the sortGrid() will be executed in recursively.

Hope it help, thanks :)